# How to parse JSON using GSON in android

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I am developing an application where I want to hit the web services and get the data. I am using `Google Volley` to hit the web service. I am doing it all right but unable to parse `JSON` using `GSON`. I am unable to understand where I am doing it wrong.

[Here is the URL of Web Services](https://api.github.com/repos/crashlytics/secureudid/issues)

Here is what I am doing

```
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(
            Request.Method.GET,
            "https://api.github.com/repos/crashlytics/secureudid/issues",
            null,
            new MyListner(),
            new MyErrorListner()
    );

    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);

}

class MyListner implements Response.Listener<JSONObject>
{
    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Results results = gson.fromJson(response.toString(), Results.class);

        for(Test t : results.getmResults())
        {
            Log.e("Tag", t.toString());
        }


    }
}

class MyErrorListner implements Response.ErrorListener
{
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        Log.e("Error", error.getMessage());
    }
}
```

The other classes are given below

```
public class Results {


private ArrayList<Test> mResults;

public void setResults(ArrayList<Test> results)
{
    mResults = results;
}

public ArrayList<Test> getmResults()
{
    return mResults;
}
}

public class Test {

@SerializedName("title")
private String mTitle;

@SerializedName("user")
private User mUser;

@SerializedName("created_at")
private String mCreatedAt;

@SerializedName("body")
private String mBody;

@SerializedName("updated_at")
private String mUpdatedAt;

public String getmBody() {
    return mBody;
}

public void setmBody(String mBody) {
    this.mBody = mBody;
}

public String getmUpdatedAt() {
    return mUpdatedAt;
}

public void setmUpdatedAt(String mUpdatedAt) {
    this.mUpdatedAt = mUpdatedAt;
}

public String getmCreatedAt() {
    return mCreatedAt;
}

public void setmCreatedAt(String mCreatedAt) {
    this.mCreatedAt = mCreatedAt;
}

public User getmUser() {
    return mUser;
}

public void setmUser(User mUser) {
    this.mUser = mUser;
}

public String getmTitle() {
    return mTitle;
}

public void setmTitle(String mTitle) {
    this.mTitle = mTitle;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return mTitle + " " + mBody + " " + mCreatedAt + " " + mUpdatedAt + " " + mUser.getmLogin() + " ";
}
}


public class User {

@SerializedName("login")
private String mLogin;

public String getmLogin() {
    return mLogin;
}

public void setmLogin(String mLogin) {
    this.mLogin = mLogin;
}
}
```

Here is the error what I am getting

```
org.json.JSONException:  Value [{"url":"https:\/\/api.github.com\/repos\/crashlytics\/secureudid\/issues\/28","repository_url":"https:\/\/api.github.com\/repos\/crashlytics\/secureudid","labels_url":"https:\/\/api.github.com\/repos\/crashlytics\/secureudid\/issues\/28\/labels{\/name}","comments_url":"https:\/\/api.github.com\/repos\/crashlytics\/secureudid\/issues\/28\/comments","events_url":"https:\/\/api.github.com\/repos\/crashlytics\/secureudid\/issues\/28\/events","html_url":"https:\/\/github.com\/crashlytics\/secureudid\/pull\/28","id":222258999,"number":28,"title":"Fix broken headings in Markdown files","user":{"login":"bryant1410","id":3905501,"avatar_url":"https:\/\/avatars3.githubusercontent.com\/u\/3905501?v=4","gravatar_id":"","url":"https:\/\/api.github.com\/users\/bryant1410","html_url":"https:\/\/github.com\/bryant1410","followers_url":"https:\/\/api.github.com\/users\/bryant1410\/followers","following_url":"https:\/\/api.github.com\/users\/bryant1410\/following{\/other_user}","gists_url":"https:\/\/api.github.com\/users\/bryant1410\/gists{\/gist_id}","starred_url":"https:\/\/api.github.com\/users\/bryant1410\/starred{\/owner}{\/repo}","subscriptions_url":"https:\/\/api.github.com\/users\/bryant1410\/subscriptions","organizations_url":"https:\/\/api.github.com\/users\/bryant1410\/orgs","repos_url":"https:\/\/api.github.com\/users\/bryant1410\/repos","events_url":"https:\/\/api.github.com\/users\/bryant1410\/events{\/privacy}","received_events_url":"https:\/\/api.github.com\/users\/bryant1410\/received_events","type":"User","site_admin":false},"labels":[],"state":"open","locked":false,"assignee":null,"assignees":[],"milestone":null,"comments":0,"created_at":"2017-04-17T23:26:47Z","updated_at":"2017-04-17T23:26:47Z","closed_at":null,"author_association":"NONE","pull_request":{"url":"https:\/\/api.github.com\/repos\/crashlytics\/secureudid\/pulls\/28","html_url":"https:\/\/github.com\/crashlytics\/secureudid\/pull\/28","diff_url":"https:\/\/github.com\/crashlytics\/secureudid\/pull\/28.diff","patch_url":"https:\/\/github.com\/crashlytics\/secureudid\/pull\/28.patch"},"body":"GitHub changed the way Markdown headings are parsed, so this change fixes it.\n\nSee [bryant1410\/readmesfix](https:\/\/github.com\/bryant1410\/readmesfix) for more information.\n\nTackles bryant1410\/readmesfix#1\n"},{"url":"https:\/\/api.github.com\/repos\/crashlytics\/secureudid\/issues\/13","repository_url":"https:\/\/api.github.com\/repos\/crashlytics\/secureudid","labels_url":"https:\/\/api.github.com\/repos\/crashlytics\/secureudid\/issues\/13\/labels{\/name}","comments_url":"https:\/\/api.github.com\/repos\/crashlytics\/secureudid\/issues\/13\/comments","events_url":"https:\/\/api.github.com\/repos\/crashlytics\/secureudid\/issues\/13\/events","html_url":"https:\/\/github.com\/crashlytics\/secureudid\/issues\/13","id":3923240,"number":13,"title":"Not working with ARC","user":{"login":"SaschaMoellering","id":1321549,"avatar_url":"https:\/\/avatars0.githubusercontent.com\/u\/1321549?v=4","gravatar_id":"","url":"https:\/\/api.github.com\/users\/SaschaMoellering","html_url":"https:\/\/github.com\/SaschaMoellering","followers_url":"https:\/\/api.github.com\/users\/SaschaMoellering\/followers","following_url":"https:\/\/api.github.com\/users\/SaschaMoellering\/following{\/other_user}","gists_url":"https:\/\/api.github.com\/users\/SaschaMoellering\/gists{\/gist_id}","starred_url":"https:\/\/api.github.com\/users\/SaschaMoellering\/starred{\/owner}{\/repo}","subscriptions_url":"https:\/\/api.github.com\/users\/SaschaMoellering\/subscriptions","organizations_url":"https:\/\/api.github.com\/users\/SaschaMoellering\/orgs","repos_url":"https:\/\/api.github.com\/users\/SaschaMoellering\/repos","events_url":"https:\/\/api.github.com\/users\/SaschaMoellering\/events{\/privacy}","received_events_url":"https:\/\/api.github.com\/users\/SaschaMoellering\/received_events","type":"User","site_admin":false},"labels":[],"state":"open","locked":false,"assignee":null,"assignees":[],"milestone":null,"comments":10,"created_at":"20
```

Comment: Your exception's message should have more text than that. Please post the whole thing.

Comment: Consider reading the official tutorial on using GSON with Volley instead of parsing then unparsing then parsing the response on the UI thread.... https://developer.android.com/training/volley/request-custom.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to parse an array of object (from your webservices) to an object containing a property `mResults` which is an array of object (`Test`);

Instead of using `Results` class during parsing you need to directly use an `ArrayList` of `Test`:

```
Results results = gson.fromJson(response.toString(), Results.class);
```

should be

```
ArrayList<Test> results = gson.fromJson(response.toString(), new TypeToken<ArrayList<Test>>(){}.getType());
```

As ArrayList is a generic it's **not possible to use** `ArrayList<Test>.class` to get a representation of the data type, we must use [TypeToken](https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.6.2/com/google/gson/reflect/TypeToken.html). What is TypeToken?

> TypeToken represents a generic type T. Java doesn't yet provide a way to
>   represent generic types, so this class does. Forces clients to create
>   a subclass of this class which enables retrieval the type information
>   even at runtime.

`getType` returns the type of the class used to build TypeToken and so we can use it in gson [`fromJson()`](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html#fromJson-java.lang.String-java.lang.reflect.Type-) parsing method.

--

Second problem:

Your are using `JsonObjectRequest` but server response is a Json array so you need to use `JsonArrayRequest` and so update `MyListner` to use `JSONArray` instead of `JSONObject`.

*BUT*

As your are parsing server response manually you can use `StringRequest` and so avoid parsing step of `Volley`.

```
StringRequest jsonObjectRequest = new StringRequest(
    Request.Method.GET,
    "https://api.github.com/repos/crashlytics/secureudid/issues",
    new MyListner(),
    new MyErrorListner()
);
```

and `MyListner` is now directly using `String`:

```
class MyListner implements Response.Listener<String> {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        ArrayList<Test> results = gson.fromJson(response, new TypeToken<ArrayList<Test>>() {}.getType());

        for (Test t : results) {
            Log.e("Tag", t.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer but still could not solve the error. I think there is problem with results class

Comment: @AkshayNaik Indeed there was another mistake, I  update my answer. It's must be ok now (I try it on a playground project and it's working ;))

Comment: Maisse Hey, thanks for solution I solved it I just need one more help can you tell me what new TypeToken<Arraylist<Object>>(){}.getType() do in particular

Comment: @AkshayNaik , answer completed and also updated JsonObjectRequest pb related part. Is it ok ?

Comment: Yes the answer is complety fine. It worked thanks for the same.